# Matrix operations in Excel: Populate new matrix from values from two matrices?

Tags: excel, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have two matrices in different sheets of excel worksheet (also have csvs), image attached.
[image: Snapshot of existing matrices and desired output]

Matrix1) Series of elements on x, across stations in y

Matrix2) Series of charges on x, across elements on y

I want to create MATRIX 3 incorporating: Station as Y (column) Charges as X (rows) The charges are the multiplication of each element in the station*that particular charge and the addition of all the values. It makes more sense in the image. I can do it manually and it is tedious and time consuming to do across hundreds of observations and I need to changed the values across each row.

I know there are methods to do this with MMULT and I have attempted it but still need to change values when moving across. I tried the following:

`=MMULT(B4:F4, I$4:I$8)`

where B4 represents the first cell of the first elements for station 1 in matrix 1 and F4 is the last cell for last element in matrix 1. Meanwhile, I$4 - I$8 are all the elements with a specific charge in matrix 2. In matrix 3, it includes the multiplication and addition of all these cells for the cell in matrix 3, e.g. the negative charge cell for all elements in station 1. The other attempts as evident in the image is simple multiplication and addition , not using any matrix functions.

I am a bit stuck and look forward to your help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you could combine SUMPRODUCT and TRANSPOSE ?

Answer (score 0):

Based purely on your example, this works. It assumes the rows and columns in the output matrix are in the same order as the input matrices.

This formula in E14 copied down and across.

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B4:$F4,TRANSPOSE(I$4:I$8))
```

[image]